# Shopify customer auto tag stopped working

Tags: shopify, liquid

Two of websites which work based on auto tagging of customer accounts created through the register page (so that the tagged users see a reduced price). There was some update in the Shopify Admin and both of them stopped working this morning. I was using something like

```
<input type="hidden" id="customer_tags" name="customer[tags]" value="wholesaler"/>
```

Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you find a resolution to this. I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, we could not find a workaround, so are working on an app to achieve this. I'll post the link here once it is released. We expect it to be ready in another week or so.

Comment: Shopify have acknowledged there's an issue given there's a number of people experiencing the same problem. Will see what they respond with as well.

Comment: Oh, good to know that. Is there any forum link or anything where I can follow the updates?

Comment: I too have this issue. This bug breaks vital functionality on our shop. I can't find anything in the Shopify forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

The issue has now been fixed:

> As of right now it appears that the customer tagging feature is back in business and working again on customer registration forms, I've just tested it using "name="customer[tags]"" and have been able to create a tagged account so all looks to be well.
>
> Josh Wheeler
> Shopify Support

---

I've been in touch with Shopify back and forth and this is the latest answer as of 10 minutes ago. It looks like they've now confirmed this as a bug and a fix is on the way:

> Just wanted to reach out you let you know that the issue with tagging customers upon registration is one that we're looking into and should have fixed soon. While it isn't related to the multi-channel update itself, it does seem like the timing coincides with a change made here to be honest. Apologies for any problems this is causing!
>
> I'll be in touch again as soon as we have a fix rolled out!
>
> Regards,
> Josh Wheeler
> Shopify Support

Comment: Thanks for the information Joe. It'll be great if you could post here once you get a confirmation from Shopify that this is fixed.

Comment: I've had a further notification from Josh @ Shopify stating that the bug has been fixed.  I've checked on my on site and this does appear to be fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately its still not working for me. @simnom - did you have to do any update or anything for the fix to be reflected?

Comment: @Joe - did you get a chance to verify if it is working for you?

Comment: OK, one of my two sites seems to be working fine now. I'll check what's wrong with the other one

Comment: Both my stores back now...We applied some changes while trying to fix it which was causing it to stop working after the Shopify fix. Everything fine now :) Thanks guys for keeping us in loop about the fix...and of course thanks to Josh Wheeler :)